# Text is printed incorrectly using ZPL

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I print a text using ZPL but they are printed incorrectly. It has gaps in the middle. They are printed correctly to the real printer via the ZebraDesigner. But they are wrong when printing via ZPL:

```
^FT246,70^A0R,16,16
^FB900,2,,
^FDMaisstaerke, Austernuce, Cashewnuss,Pilz, Mais,              Lattich, Pack Choi,Sojasprossen^FS
```

It is printed as 'Maisstaerke, Austernuce, Cashewnuss,Pilz, Mais,                   Lattich, Pack Choi, Sojasprossen'

(there is a big gap after 'Mais,').

http://screencast.com/t/sTiaxC3cMg

http://screencast.com/t/0QkypnsPyF89

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Anyone help me please !. This is urgent task that I must solve :)

Comment: No one can help me?. I have tried many ways and verify each line of code but i cannot find any thing wrong. Please see the attach file:

Comment: This file print only 2 text lines but i also had issue in real machine.
Could anyone help please ?


CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
 
^XA
^PW560
^LL560
^LS0
  
^FX LINE 1 ^FS
^A0R,14,14
^FT350,70
^FB450,1,0,J
^FH_
^FDZutaten: Poulet Brust (CH), Cashewnuss 4%, Pilz, Mais, Lattich, Pack, Sojasprossen,
^FS
 
^FX LINE 2 ^FS
^A0R,14,14
^FT330,70
^FB450,1,0,J
^FH_
^FDLauch, Zwiebeln, Pepperoni Rot, Karotte, Tomatenpuree, Sojasauce, Fischsauce,
^FS
  
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Comment: There is no one can help me ?. I am stuck.

Comment: Downvoted as the links are 404 and the ZPL code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue, but the field block width seems rather large; you didn't specify any label dimensions in the original post. If you use the following code--a combination from the original post and your comments:

```
^XA
    ^PW560
    ^LL560
    ^LS0
    ^FO246,70^GB28,300,,^FS
    ^FT246,70^A0R,16,16 ^FB300,2,, ^FDMaisstaerke, Austernuce, Cashewnuss,Pilz, Mais, Lattich, Pack Choi,Sojasprossen^FS
    ^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

I can reproduce what is possibly the issue--the field block automatic word wrapping--by reducing the field block width to 300 dots.

I also drew a box around the block for visualization. You can test in on the [Labelary Viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html).

Finally, if you're somehow composing the data make sure there are no special (non printable, such as tab, non-UTF-8 or accented) characters in it, and if so, you will have to pre-escape them.